# cross_val_score giving an error - Why is this?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am trying to follow a machine-learning tutorial listed here: https://machinelearningmastery.com/machine-learning-in-python-step-by-step/, but I am encountering an issue. I was able to run the following code on my Macbook air, however, it did not work on my Windows machine. I checked other questions with similar titles, none of which seem to fit my problem.

Why is this happening? How can it be fixed?

My entire code:

```
# Python version
import sys

print('Python: {}'.format(sys.version))
# scipy
import scipy

print('scipy: {}'.format(scipy.__version__))
# numpy
import numpy

print('numpy: {}'.format(numpy.__version__))
# matplotlib
import matplotlib

print('matplotlib: {}'.format(matplotlib.__version__))
# pandas
import pandas

print('pandas: {}'.format(pandas.__version__))
# scikit-learn
import sklearn

print('sklearn: {}'.format(sklearn.__version__))

# compare algorithms
from pandas import read_csv
from matplotlib import pyplot
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedKFold
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
from sklearn.discriminant_analysis import LinearDiscriminantAnalysis
from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB
from sklearn.svm import SVC

# Load dataset
url = "energyFormatted.csv"
names = ['TOTAL', 'PURCHASED', 'NUCLEAR', 'SOLAR', 'WIND', 'NATURAL_GAS', 'COAL', 'OIL']
dataset = read_csv(url, names=names)
print(dataset.shape)

# Split-out validation dataset
array = dataset.values
X = array[:, 0:4]
y = array[:, 4]
X_train, X_validation, Y_train, Y_validation = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.20, random_state=1, shuffle=True)
# Spot Check Algorithms
models = []
models.append(('LR', LogisticRegression(solver='liblinear', multi_class='ovr')))
models.append(('LDA', LinearDiscriminantAnalysis()))
models.append(('KNN', KNeighborsClassifier()))
models.append(('CART', DecisionTreeClassifier()))
models.append(('NB', GaussianNB()))
models.append(('SVM', SVC(gamma='auto')))
# evaluate each model in turn
results = []
names = []
for name, model in models:
    kfold = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=10, random_state=1, shuffle=True)
    cv_results = cross_val_score(model, X_train, Y_train, cv=kfold, scoring='accuracy')
    results.append(cv_results)
    names.append(name)
    print('%s: %f (%f)' % (name, cv_results.mean(), cv_results.std()))
```

The line that's giving me an error:

```
cv_results = cross_val_score(model, X_train, Y_train, cv=kfold, scoring='accuracy')
```

The error itself:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Applications\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\joblib\parallel.py", line 862, in dispatch_one_batch
    tasks = self._ready_batches.get(block=False)
  File "C:\Users\danie\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\queue.py", line 168, in get
    raise Empty
_queue.Empty

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\danie\AppData\Roaming\JetBrains\PyCharmCE2022.2\scratches\FY23 SCI FAIR\main.py", line 63, in <module>
    cv_results = cross_val_score(model, X_train, Y_train, cv=kfold, scoring=None)
  File "D:\Applications\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_validation.py", line 515, in cross_val_score
    cv_results = cross_validate(
  File "D:\Applications\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_validation.py", line 266, in cross_validate
    results = parallel(
  File "D:\Applications\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\joblib\parallel.py", line 1085, in __call__
    if self.dispatch_one_batch(iterator):
  File "D:\Applications\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\joblib\parallel.py", line 873, in dispatch_one_batch
    islice = list(itertools.islice(iterator, big_batch_size))
  File "D:\Applications\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_validation.py", line 266, in <genexpr>
    results = parallel(
  File "D:\Applications\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_split.py", line 340, in split
    for train, test in super().split(X, y, groups):
  File "D:\Applications\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_split.py", line 86, in split
    for test_index in self._iter_test_masks(X, y, groups):
  File "D:\Applications\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_split.py", line 717, in _iter_test_masks
    test_folds = self._make_test_folds(X, y)
  File "D:\Applications\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_split.py", line 660, in _make_test_folds
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: Supported target types are: ('binary', 'multiclass'). Got 'continuous' instead.
```

CSV:

```
28564,0,6284.08,1713.84,19.9948,19994.8,19.9948,19.9948
28411,0,6250.42,852.33,0,20740.03,568.22,0
27515,0,6053.3,550.3,0,20361.1,550.3,0
24586,491.72,5408.92,245.86,0,17947.78,491.72,0
26653,533.06,6130.19,0,0,18923.63,1066.12,0
26836,805.08,6172.28,0,0,18785.2,1073.44,0
26073,1303.65,5736.06,0,0,17990.37,1042.92,0
27055,1352.75,6222.65,0,0,18397.4,1082.2,0
26236,1311.8,6034.28,0,0,17578.12,1311.8,0
26020,1821.4,3903,0,0,18994.6,1040.8,260.2
26538,0,4246.08,265.38,13799.76,6369.12,0,1326.9
25800,3354,5160,0,0,14964,1290,1032
26682,3468.66,5603.22,0,0,14941.92,1600.92,1067.28
24997,3499.58,5499.34,0,0,13248.41,1499.82,1249.85
25100,3765,4769,0,0,13052,1506,2008
24651,4190.67,4930.2,0,0,12325.5,1232.55,1972.08
12053,0,1084.77,0,3133.78,6508.62,0,723.18
11500,2070,2415,0,0,4255,690,2070
```

Comment: I have reason to believe that the csv is the problem since the iris dataset seems to work fine. I have attached it to the question. I will answer it myself if I figure it out before anyone here does.

Answer (score 0):

Accuracy doesn't make sense for scoring a continuous variable. The error indicates that your `y` values are of type `float` (or are otherwise continuous). You could try something like [`sklearn.metrics.mean_squared_error`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.mean_squared_error.html) instead of accuracy.

Comment: I tried that but I just got a different error - and when I fixed it a very similar one to the first time. I can't add it here because of the character limit, however, if you want to see it I can add it to the original post.